# "Я остался дома" или "я остался в доме"?

Tags: выбор-слов, падежи, лексическая-сочетаемость

Mожно ли говорить "я остался дома"? Ведь здесь должен быть предложный падеж и предлог. Если эта форма допустима, какой частью речи является слово "дома" здесь, и можно ли сказать "я остался в доме"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дома — наречие со значением "у себя в доме".

Я остался (где?) дома  — распространённый вариант, когда имеешь в виду собственное жильё:

*Я остался дома, а они ушли. Я остался дома, а все пошли в гости.* Это можно сказать, имея в виду не только дом, но и квартиру.

Я остался в доме — речь только о доме как жилом здании, не обязательно о своём.

*Я остался в доме, а она ушла на квартиру. Я остался в доме, а все побежали на речку.*